# Passing variable into JavaScript getElementById

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a simple JavaScript problem. Here is an example:

```
function test()
{    
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {         
      var value[i] = 100*i;         
      var x = accountname + value[i];

      document.getElementById(x).value = value + '_'+"TestName";        
    }        
}
```

```asp
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

    <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="accountname100" AutoCompleteType="HomePhone" runat="server"
        Label="account #1:" /><br />
    <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="accountname200" AutoCompleteType="HomePhone" runat="server"
        Label="account  #2:" /><br />
    <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="accountname300" AutoCompleteType="HomePhone" runat="server"
        Label="account  #3:" /><br />
    <telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="accountname400" AutoCompleteType="HomePhone" runat="server"
        Label="account  #4:" /><br />

</asp:Content>
```

I am trying to find the correct syntax so that the value of parameter "x" can be in the radtextbox correctly.

Comment: where is `accountname` defined?

Comment: telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="accountname100" Width="200px" TextMode="Password"></telerik:RadTextBox>

telerik:RadTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="accountname200" Width="200px" TextMode="Password"></telerik:RadTextBox>

the id will be accountname100

Comment: You should add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

here is some seems to you pretended

```
function test() {
    value = [];
    for(var i=1; i<5; i++) {
        value.push(100*i);
        var x = accountname + value[i];
        document.getElementById('accountname'+x).value = value + '_' + "TestName";
    }
}
```

**Details:**

in javascript vars don't have types their type is dinamic

so to declarate any type of variable you have to do this

```
var number = 10;
var name = "Jhon";
var money = 3.23;
var arrayNumbers = [1,2];
```

I suggest you to see some basic guide to javascript.

Comment: Thanks for spending u time on this problem. 

"x " here is dynamic. If i use the below it is working well.

function test() { 
        document.getElementById("accountname100").value = value + '_' + "TestName";
    }
}

but it is not working if the id we are getting is dynamic

Comment: I just fixed your syntax's errors. if you wish to get a element you have to refer its id. "x" is not the id, the id is accountname+x

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few issues here. One is using `value` to set the value of the input when it has never been set and another is using `accountname`, when it should be a string `"accountname"`. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6ku7pc8/) which is roughly what I think you're trying to achieve. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. When i am trying use this function for rad textbox, I came across issue "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: What html does the rad textbox output?

Comment: @ama it occured to me that as these are Telerik Rad controls and because it will be within a web form page it will modify the id you specify, therefore you may be better off defining a custom attribute or class to target the html element output by the control